# Применяю jquery toggle на кнопку, а этот блок прячется, что делать?

Tags: jquery, javascript

При hover все нормально работает, а применяю toggle этот блок прячется, вот ссылка http://mackay.kz/source/ иконка справа книзу, play, 
сам код, там как видите 2 иконки play и home,

```
<div class="control_block">
    <i class="icon-play icon-white" id="play-music-block"></i>
    <a href="/"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></a>
</div>
```

теперь скрипт,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#play-music-block').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('icon-play').addClass('icon-pause');
        $('.muz_block').html('<audio src="/media/changeofseasons.mp3" autoplay id="music-rock" style="opacity:1; position:absolute; top:0;right:0;"></audio>');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('icon-play').removeClass('icon-pause');
        $('.muz_block').html('');
    });

});
```

p.s. шаблон на bootstrap от twitter

Comment: Покажите пример с toggle

Comment: В документации написано With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements. Вы используете toggle без параметров?

Comment: а чего сделать-то надо? :)